# C Code- E0000301 Error code while installing driver on x64 machine

Tags: c, 64-bit, drivers

Here is my code, it is complied at Visual Studio '12 for x64 platform. I intend to install a driver. Its returning E0000301. What does it mean?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Difxapi.h>



#pragma comment(lib, "Difxapi.lib")

int main()
{
    BOOL reboot;
    DWORD result;
    result=DriverPackageInstall("driverinstall.inf", 0, NULL, &reboot);
    printf("%08X\n", result);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `0xE0000301 ERROR_NO_DEVICE_ID` 
The driver package does not specify a hardware identifier or compatible identifier that is supported by the current platform.